# Binding has not yet been initialized. When Using isloates

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, isolate

** I am creating google map location app

I tried to resolve my self but i am not able to fix this bug

Please help me to fix this bug

i am getting error when i create isolate for get location

I have used packages

- google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8
- geocoding: ^2.0.4
- geolocator: ^8.2.1
- flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  **

**i got error**

```
> Restarted application in 2,738ms.
D/MapsInitializer( 6872): preferredRenderer: null
D/zzca    ( 6872): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Maps Android API( 6872): Google Play services package version: 221215028
I/Google Maps Android API( 6872): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
7
I/Counters( 6872): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
> 
> I/m.example.g_ma( 6872): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 17476(988KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 7MB/14MB, paused 172us total 133.433ms
10
I/Counters( 6872): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
I/m.example.g_ma( 6872): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 4201(193KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 7MB/14MB, paused 138us total 149.308ms
7
I/Counters( 6872): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
I/chatty  ( 6872): uid=10498(com.example.g_map) androidmapsapi- identical 1 line
3
I/Counters( 6872): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
E/flutter ( 6872): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(1098)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 6872): Binding has not yet been initialized.
E/flutter ( 6872): The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
E/flutter ( 6872): Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
E/flutter ( 6872): In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
E/flutter ( 6872): If ServicesBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be constructed before using the "instance" getter.
E/flutter ( 6872): #0      BindingBase.checkInstance.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/binding.dart:281
E/flutter ( 6872): #1      BindingBase.checkInstance
package:flutter/…/foundation/binding.dart:363
E/flutter ( 6872): #2      ServicesBinding.instance
package:flutter/…/services/binding.dart:48
E/flutter ( 6872): #3      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:132

**My Code is **

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
    import 'package:g_map/cubit/googlemap_cubit.dart';
    // import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    import 'screens/home_page.dart';
    
    void main() async{
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
       
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider<GooglemapCubit>(
        create: (context) => GooglemapCubit(),
        child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Map'),
      ),
      );
     }
    }



 

    import 'dart:developer';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

    class GLocationPermission{

    Future<bool> checkPermission()async{
      bool serviceEnabled ;
      LocationPermission permission;
    
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if(!serviceEnabled){
      log("",error: "Location service is not enabled");
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if(permission == LocationPermission.denied){
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

      if(permission == LocationPermission.denied){
        log("Permission is denied again ");
      }
    }

    if(permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever){
      log("",error: "Location permission denied forever");
      return false;
    }


    if(permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse || permission == LocationPermission.always){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
    }
    }




        import 'dart:developer';
        import 'dart:isolate';
    
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
        import 'package:g_map/isolates/current_location_in_background.dart';
        import 'package:g_map/services/location_permission.dart';
        import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
        // import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
        import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
        // import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    
        class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
          const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
    
          final String title;
    
         @override
         State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
        }
    
        class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{
           late GoogleMapController _mapController;
           final TextEditingController _searchAddressController = TextEditingController();
           final _locationPermission = GLocationPermission();
           String searchedAddress = "";
    
           late ReceivePort _receivePort;
           late Isolate _isolate;
    
           @override
           void initState() {
             _checkPermission();
             super.initState();
            }
    
            Future<void> _checkPermission()async{
             if(await _locationPermission.checkPermission() == true){
             createIsloate();
            }
           }
    
      
      
    
           Future<void> createIsloate()async{
             _receivePort = ReceivePort();
             _isolate = await Isolate.spawn(CurrentLocationInBackGround.getLocation,  _receivePort.sendPort);
        _receivePort.listen((message) {
          log("message $message");
          // final pos = message as Stream;
          // pos.listen((event) {
          //   log("Event $event");
          // });
    
        },
        onError: (error){
          log("Error $error",error: error);
        }
        );
    
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                _googleMap(
                    inititalCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
                )),
                _searchAddressField(context: context)
              ],
            ));
      }
    
      Widget _googleMap({required CameraPosition inititalCameraPosition}) {
        
          // buildWhen: (previous, current) => current.runtimeType == ,
            return GoogleMap(
              // minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(1, 20),
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: inititalCameraPosition,
            );
      
      }
    
      Widget _searchAddressField({required BuildContext context}){
        return Card(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.07,
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value){
                  // searchedAddress = context.read<GooglemapCubit>().searchAddress(address: value);
                },
                controller: _searchAddressController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none,
                suffix: IconButton(onPressed:() => _searchAndNavigate(context: context), icon: const Icon(Icons.search))
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> _searchAndNavigate({required BuildContext context})async{
            final location = GeocodingPlatform.instance.locationFromAddress(_searchAddressController.text);
            location.then((value){
            debugPrint(value[0].latitude.toString());
            debugPrint(value[0].longitude.toString());
            _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
              zoom: 12,
              target:LatLng(value[0].latitude, value[0].longitude))));
          });   
       
      }
    
      void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
        // _mapController = context.read<GooglemapCubit>().assignControllerOn(controller);
        _mapController = controller;
      }
    }




    import 'dart:developer';
    import 'dart:isolate';
    
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    
    class CurrentLocationInBackGround{
    
      
      static void getLocation(SendPort sendPort)async{
      
       final pos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
       log("pos stream $pos");
        sendPort.send(pos);
       
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before `runApp()` in your main method?

Comment: Yes i have used

Comment: Can you please provide your code, how are you using `isolates` & when, and when do you call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`

Comment: Could you please check above code

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to run **geocoding** methods on isolate because it's freezer the main thread

```
await placemarkFromCoordinates()
```

or

```
await  locationFromAddress()
```

will freeze the main thread this bug on there repository

but here is a great solution

[link to solution](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geocoding/issues/58#issuecomment-891315068)